# Do you sweat when swimming?

Tags: swimming

Just curious about this topic, because I only do swimming for fitness purpose, and I'm worrying whether the cold water blocks the sweating mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this article from the [Catalyst at Brown University](http://students.brown.edu/Catalyst/Swimming-Mitchell.html), **yes** and **no**.

> After 295 observations, the results were in. Do you sweat when you
>   swim? Sort of. Swimmers averaged a sweat rate of 123 milliliters per
>   kilometer swum, but this number is significantly lower than average
>   sweat rates for other types of exercise (about a third of the sweat
>   rate for running and half that of cycling).

This article references an Australian study **"Body mass changes and voluntary fluid intakes of elite level water polo players and swimmers."** by Cox G. R., E. M. Broad and L. M. Burke, found [behind this paywall](http://www.ausport.gov.au/ais/nutrition/research/during_exercise#3). It claims that:

> The calculated average sweat rate and fluid intake rate during
>   training sessions for male water polo players was 287 ml/h and 142
>   ml/h, respectively, with a rate of 786 ml/h and 380 ml/h during
>   matches.  During training sessions for male swimmers, the calculated
>   average sweat rate and fluid intake rate per kilometre was 138 ml/km
>   and 155 ml/km, respectively; and for female swimmers, 107 ml/km and 95
>   ml/km.

Comment: epic answer! So regardless of the the amount of sweating, People do sweat while exercise in the water.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm worrying whether the cold water blocks the sweating mechanism

Don't worry.  Your body will sweat as needed when swimming.